# Android Studio Startup - MaxJavaStackTraceDepth = -1 is outside the allowed range - ERROR

Tags: java, android, android-studio, jvm

When I launch Android Studio (Windows 10, 64 bit), I get this error :

[image: Error screenschot]

Error typed out:

```
MaxJavaStackTraceDepth=-1 is outside the allowed range[0 ... 1073741823].
Improperly specified VM option 'MaxJavaStackTraceDepth=-1'

Failed to create JVM. JVM Path: C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\jre
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are not running on Java 9, this is still experimental for Android Studio / IntelliJ.

Secondly, if you are attempting to run this on Java 9, you'll want to fall back to the bundled JVM for Android Studio and you will most likely need to tweak the Android Studio JVM settings.

It is claiming that `MaxJavaStackTraceDepth=-1` is set on your IDE startup arguments.

See this [answer from JetBrain's blog about a similar issue](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360000008244/comments/360000014950).

Beyond that, after you follow the instructions in this post, you could attempt re-installing Android Studio (I would ***not*** import previous installation settings), because it definitely appears that something is misconfigured for your installation.